# Can't load Geometry package

Tags: packages

I am trying to use `` << Geometry`Rotations ``; but I got this message

> Get::noopen: Cannot open Geometry`Rotations`. >>".

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You have to put the package to $UserBaseDirectory/Applications, or wherever on `$Path`.

Comment: Actually this is found with a plain google search https://www.google.fr/search?q=mathematica%20geometry%20rotations&oq=mathematica%20geometry%20rotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package is no longer available in recent Mathematica versions.  It has been replaced with builtin functionality.  Please read here:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Geometry/Rotations.html